# Javascript for Blackberry Bold that allows user to select a country and then the text field will accept the proper formated zip code

Tags: javascript, blackberry

This is for a Blackberry browser app for Blackberry Bold 9700 & 9650 running the 5.0 browser. I want the user to select US or Canada from a drop down then based on that selection the following input text field will allow the proper zip code formatting. Alpha and numeric if Canada is selected in drop down or just numeric if US is selected in drop down.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Travis

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <label for="country">
            Country:
        </label>
        <select id="country" name="country">
            <option value="usa">USA</option>
            <option value="canada">Canada</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="zip">
            Zip:</label>
        <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" />
    </p>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var countrySelect = document.getElementById('country');
        var zipInput = document.getElementById('zip');

        function validateZip(evt) {

            // regex obtained from http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=2494
            var usZipRegex = /^(\d{5}-\d{4}|\d{5}|\d{9})$/;
            var canZipRegex = /^([a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-Z]( )?\d[a-zA-Z]\d)$/;
            var zipRegex;

            var country = countrySelect.value;

            if (country === 'usa') {
                zipRegex = usZipRegex;
            }
            else if (country === 'canada') {
                zipRegex = canZipRegex;
            }

            var valid = zipRegex.test(zipInput.value);
            alert(valid ? 'Valid' : 'Invalid');
        }

        zipInput.onchange = validateZip;

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```